# How does IOS devices read javascript in browser?

Tags: javascript, ios, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I had previously asked a question about my test project.

The dropdown which is most likely using `boostrap.min.js` works only in Android currently. We've changed the location of the folders so that the linked boostrap js is now like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`. Notice the `../` part was added. There are no problems reading the file on non-IOS based devices. When we check on the Iphone, the dropdown doesn't work. So I thought maybe its how Safari reads the CSS or Javascript?

Here is the site btw: http://star-allianz.com/en/en/index.html

I don't own an Iphone5 or Iphone6+ so its hard for me to test things.

Note: The missing files aren't a problem because the dropdowns still work in my Android phone.

PS: I've tried using online IOS device simulators and the built-in Google Chrome simulator. The dropdowns work even when I load the site. However, when using a real IOS device, they don't. Keep in mind, it works in Android. Also, I've never made any changes to `bootstrap.min.js`.

Comment: If you have a mac, you can debug the web content inside the ios app directly from Safari

Comment: If I have one, I'd surely do so. Thanks for the info but currently I need some clarity over this kind of case.